# How to access the values in a dynamic dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary which is dynamically generated. In the dictionary, for a single Key, there are multiple values. I am trying to access one of the values in those multiple values. My code so far:

```
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var dictionary = deserialisedResult as IDictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            result.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        object o = result;
        string[] names = o.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        foreach (var prop in names)
        {
            object propValue = o.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(o, null);
            var value = propValue.GetValue(o,null);
        }
```

But this is not working.

I need to get the values for 'resource'.

When I add watch, I see it nested as such:

[image]

Comment: First of all, looks like you deserialized a payload/something to get this dictionary. Would be nice to see a sample of that firsthand. And when you said there are multiple values for one key, did you mean it's a dictionary with a List of values assigned to a single key?

Comment: Maybe tell us whats the desired output , what are you getting as error or output right now? This watch is not enough window .. at least to me.

Comment: I really need more information to process this, if it's a List of values attached to one key serialize as IDictionary<string, List<something>> and might turn out better for you.

If you go through properties in the object o here which is essentially a dictionary, you're literally browsing every property that instance type has, not essentially the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: If you're using C# 4 or later, you could try leveraging `dynamic`: `((dynamic) item.Value).resource`. This has absolutely nothing to do with the dictionary, however, which just happens to store a bunch of values. A dictionary does *not* store multiple values per key, it stores only one. If your value is some sort of collection, that's another matter. See what `item.Value.GetType()` gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following line is causing issue out here:
>
> `string[] names = o.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();`

`GetType()` for `Object` base class type will not yield a `Type`, which can provide the `PropertyInfo[]`, that you are looking for, even otherwise you are trying to run it for `Dictionary<string,object>` type, which anyway doesn't have properties to help find the relevant information. For it the `Type` would always be `Dictionary`

> What you need is fetch the key collection from Dictionary and use them to fetch the values stored in the Dictionary

```
foreach (var key in result.Keys)
{
    var value = result[key];
}
```

Solution is based on code provided in the question, I am not sure if you have further requirements